# Password change for phpmyadmin not working from config file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords

I've had to change the password for my root account for phpmyadmin (through the user accounts tab).

Before I move on, I just want to say that everything still works when using the old password, so if I reset everything back the old password, it all works fine.

just FYI 
var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php is empty

etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php does not have any mention of passwords, 
but I found the login info in etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php and changed the password there
and also in /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf

Everything I read says that just changing it in a config.inc.php file should do it, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: you want to change password for mysql `root` user ?

Comment: Yes, I've changed the root password from the user accounts tab on phpmyadmin.
My issue is that the database is not connecting to the website. 

I have tried reading other comments and changing the passwords in the files mentioned above but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Did you perform a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` query after changing the `root` password on MySQL, or click the Flush Privileges link underneath the phpMyAdmin User Account tab?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, still no luck

Comment: you may need to restart the sql service as well. On the other hand, please leverage the "code" markdown systax, will help other users to an easier read of your question.